# UITableView keyboard resizing after insertSections not working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, keyboard, resize, textfield

I've been working with a table view that allows the user to insert new data when the last cell, "ADD NEW ITEM" cell, is tapped. Each cell has some text fields inside and when one of these becomes the first responder, of course, the keyboard will show up. I decided to use the code in the following link to resize the tableview dynamically to prevent the keyboard from covering the cell being edited.

[Generic UITableView keyboard resizing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845426/generic-uitableview-keyboard-resizing-algorithm)

This code works perfectly every time I tapped any text field in a cell that was previously added, but when I add a new cell and programmatically set the text field in it as the first responder, the tableView is not being resized. I'm not an expert in objective-c and I really don't know what it's wrong. I would appreciate any help.

This is the code designed to add the new cell.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.section == self.dataController.countOfBudgetItemList)
{
    BudgetItem *newItem = [[BudgetItem alloc] initWithName:@"Name of item" price:0 quantity:1 quantityUnit:quantityUnitUnits discount:0 thumbnail:nil];

    [self.dataController addBudgetItemListObject:newItem];

    [CATransaction begin];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:
    ^{
        if(addingNewItem && indexPath.section == editingSectionNumber)
        {
            SectionTitleCell *addingNewItemTempCell = (SectionTitleCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:editingSectionNumber]];

            [addingNewItemTempCell.productNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        }

    }];

    if(editingSectionNumber >= 0)
    {
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:editingSectionNumber] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    addingNewItem = YES;
    editingSectionNumber = indexPath.section;

    [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView endUpdates];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
...
...
...
}
```

The methods that manage the number of sections in the tableView and the number of sections in each row

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(editingSectionNumber == section)
{
    return 2;
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return self.dataController.countOfBudgetItemList + 1;
}
```

I'm also using the textFieldDidBeginEditing method, so I don't know if this may cause any problem since the event that trigger this and the keyboardWillShow methods, are the same.

UPDATE:

I modified the animateWithDuration method call to show the values of tableView.frame before and after the animation, and I found that the value is properly modified in the "animations" block but it returns to its original values once the animation is completed. Why is the frame going back to its original size?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
        animations:
        ^{
            tableView.frame = tableFrame;

            NSLog(@"Origin: x=%f, y=%f", tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y);
            NSLog(@"Size: width=%f, height=%f", tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height);

            [self tableAnimationBegan];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {
            if(finished)
            {
                //self.budgetItemsTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

                NSLog(@"Origin: x=%f, y=%f", tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y);
                NSLog(@"Size: width=%f, height=%f", tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height);
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found the solution to my problem so I decided to posted here in case somebody is going through the same.

Basically all the code was working perfectly expect for the fact that I was using autolayout, I disable it and now everything works like a charm.

Apparently when I was adding the new cell programmatically the tableview was being automatically resized making it look like my code was doing absolutely nothing.