# Set Tableview y-position in a UIViewController when Keyboard shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `TableView` inside a `UIViewController` created in Main.Storyboard.
The Y-position is 0 when initialized. 
My problem is, when the keyboard shows, the Y-Position of the `TableView` doesn't change at all. The Y-position stays at 0. So the cells get's hidden behind the NavigationController.

The code so far:

```
-(void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    if (kbIsShown == false) {
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
        UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
        CGRect keyboardFrame;
        [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
        [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
        [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
        NSLog(@"frame..%f..%f..%f..%f",self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"keyboard..%f..%f..%f..%f",keyboardFrame.origin.x, keyboardFrame.origin.y, keyboardFrame.size.width, keyboardFrame.size.height);
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y - keyboardFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [chatTable setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardFrame.size.height + TABBAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-keyboardFrame.size.height)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        NSLog(@"Visar sig");
        kbIsShown = true;
    }
}
```

The `[chatTable setFrame:]` doesn't do anything. The `TableViews (chatTable)` Y-position stays at 0. How can i change the Y-position of the Tableview so my content will be visible?

Note: `[self.view setFrame...]` does actually change the Y-position of the view. But the `chatTable` stays at 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845426/generic-uitableview-keyboard-resizing-algorithm

Comment: Thanks @rakeshbs! I managed to make it work! I made some small changes!

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll your table view to desired row use:

```
[chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

you should also set:

```
chatTable.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0);
```